# my php, jquery comment system cannot display comments in right order

Tags: php, jquery

I was trying to create a commenting system like that uses facebook. I use php and jquery. My code works perfect. User writes something in textarea, comment_1 and post it. Comment_1 appears directly under the textarea successfuly. If i refresh the page I can see comment_1 posted at beginning. If I try to post a new comment (comment_2), then comment_2 appears under comment_1 and again comment_1 under comment_2. For example:

At the begining:  **comment_1**

After refresh and post new comment: **comment_1** /
                                    **comment_2**
                                    **comment_1**
So as you can see, after refresh the page it places comment_2 and under it comment_1, but also keeps comment_1 above them (like keeping comment_1 in its "memory"). If I refresh the page I will get **comment_2 comment_1** which is what I finaly want, but how can I do this without refresh? Here is my code:

wall.php

```
<?php

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){                           
$("#comment_process").click(function(){
    if($("#comment_text").val() != ""){ 
        $.post("comments.php?action=post", { comment: $("#comment_text").val() }, function(data) {
            $(".comments").html(data);
            $("#comment_text").val("");
        });
    } 
});   
});   
</script>


<div class="comment_container">
<div class="comment_form">

<textarea id="comment_text" ></textarea>
<input type="button" id="comment_process" value="Post"/>

</div>
</div>

<?php include_once("comments.php");?>

<div class="comments">   </div>

?>
```

and this is comments.php

```
<?php
function getComments(){

$comments = "";
        // use desc order by date in order to display comments by date
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY comment_date DESC ") or die (mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
                $comments = " <div class='each_comment'> There are no comments ...</div> ";
        }else{
            while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){          
                $comments .= "<fieldset> Stefanos Says : <div class='each_comment'>  <small><em> ".$row['comment_date']." </em></small><br />".$row['comment']."</div></fieldset>  </br>"; 
            }
        }

        return $comments;  

    }


function postComments($comment){

        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($comment));
        $sql = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `comments` (comment, comment_date) VALUES ('".$comment."', now()) ");
        return true;

    }



    if((isset($_GET['action'])) && ($_GET['action'] == "post")) {
        postComments($_POST['comment']);
    }

echo getComments();
?>
```

Comment: You are going to get hacked as soon as this thing goes on the internet. You can not stop a SQL injection by escaping and stripping tags. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Incorrect, [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is safe for use in production environments. The reason for switching to PDO/mysqli is to use the superior prepared statements, not an intrinsic issue with mysql library.

Comment: @LightningDust Please don't tell me I'm wrong unless you know what you are talking about. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: @MathewFoscarini What kind of idiot doesn't use quotes around a string value such as a comment's contents? Personally I refuse to move away from the `mysql` extension, simply because I see no reason to. Escaping your MySQL inputs is just as second-nature to me as `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini If you don't know the difference between a `SELECT` statement and an `INSERT` statement, I'll leave that for you to figure out by yourself. Suffice to say, the worst case scenario here is that you get junk data in the database: a comment of `1=1` (probably a valid comment).

Comment: @Kolink I refuse to move away from `mysql` extension because PDO is slower and not any safer if you know what you're doing.

Comment: guys I am confused!... what do you think of this code? safe or not? What I should change to make it safe in your opinion? :)

Comment: @user2491321 This is safe, what Mathew pointed out is an edge case for `SELECT` statements. General rule for sanitizing inputs: If it's a string sanitize input with `$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['somevalue']);` and put quotation marks around the string in the query: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE somefield = '$data'");`. If it's an int, sanitize input with `$data = (int) $_POST['somevalue']` and omit quotation marks around the variable in the query: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE somefield = $data");`

Comment: @user2491321 `strip_tags` will not prevent users from posting HTML to your comments. You need to prevent double encoded tags. `mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(strip_tags($comment)));`. Personally I'd drop all unimportant characters.

Comment: @Kolink Do you see anything wrong with the explanation in my updated answer?

Comment: @user2491321 I wouldn't use `strip_tags` in this instance because it will prevent harmless things being written in comments. You're better off using `$comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($comment))` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) so that if users write tags in their comments, they just display as part of the comment when it's re-displayed.

Comment: @LightningDust yes, `htmlspecialchars` is much better! I stand corrected :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Issues with Comments Displaying Wrong

The issue here is that you're not clearing the original comments.

Move `<?php include_once("comments.php");?>` into this div:

`<div class="comments">   </div>`

This way, when you write comments to that block with your javascript, the original comments which were loaded when the page loaded will be replaced.

### Apparent issues with MySQL injections and `mysql` extension

**Correct Practices**

How you SHOULD sanitize a string for a SELECT statement:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['some_data']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value = '$data'");
```

How you SHOULD sanitize an integer for a SELECT statement:

```
$data = (int) $_POST['some_data'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value = $data");
```

Note that the integer does not have quotation marks around it.

**The Apparent Vulnerability**

Mathew correctly pointed out in the comments that this brand of select statement (demonstrated by ircmaxell) would not correctly prevent SQL injection attacks:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['some_data']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value = $data");
```

However, this isn't a vulnerability so much as a misuse of the function, by not putting quotations around `$data` we suggest that we're searching for an integer, but we've sanitized our input as if it were a string.

If it's an integer field, we should be casting the input value as an integer. If it's a string field, there should be quotes around it in the query. All that's been displayed here is that a function can be used incorrectly.

As your `SELECT` statement does not take any user inputs and just selects ALL comments, there is no opportunity for this kind of injection anyway.